# How to change the widh of scroll indicator in uiscrollview ios?

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there any method / property to change the width of scroll indicator in `UIScrollView`. I have used the property `UIsSrollView`. *IndicatorStyle* but it can only change the color of scroll indicator.

Comment: can you please question more clear?

Comment: scroll indicator is the horizontal/vertical strip of line used to scroll in scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, you will need to write your own. Using the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate), but this would yield an answer to long for stackoverflow.